# Ticker feeds list doesn't support Unicode

Tags: bug, chat, feed

While looking at [Japanese SO's Python chatroom feeds](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/21000/python?tab=feeds), I realized that the ticker feeds doesn't display the feed's title correctly.

> ### Ticker feeds
>
> New items from these feeds will be shown via a slide-down ticker overlay that periodically appears at the top of the room, and will not be persisted.
>
> [python ????????????? - ????·???????](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=python&sort=newest) posted by [Stack Exchange](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-2/stack-exchange)

After checking the feed, the problem was identified due to the title containing Japanese characters:

> ```
> <title type="text">python タグが付けられた最新の質問 - スタック・オーバーフロー</title>
> ```

I have also tried to change the encoding to Unicode (UTF-8), Japanese (Shift_JIS, EUC-JP, ISO-2022-JP), and Western (Windows-1252), but nothing changed.

With this, I assume the problem is related to title conversion from the feed to ticker feeds.

Tested on: Chrome 40, FireFox 36 & IE 11 on Windows 7, so I doubt it's browser-dependent.

Comment: The feed's title seems to be no longer shown for *new* feeds. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/17893/?tab=feeds